# Tensorboard tf events file is too large despite having very few steps

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have pasted part of the code (all the part that refers to the tensorboard part) below. I am only recording the loss scalar variable and only adding the summary once for one epoch. I ran it for a total of 3 epochs. That should ideally be a very small tfevents file. However, the tfevents file is 1.3GB. I am not sure what is causing the file to be so big.
Happy to share the rest of the code if needed

```
def do_training(update_op, loss, summary_op):

    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        try:
            step = 0
            while True:

                if step % (X_train.shape[0]/batch_size) == 0:
                    _, loss_value = sess.run((update_op, loss))
                    summary = sess.run(summary_op)
                    writer.add_summary(summary, global_step=step)
                    print('Step {} with loss {}'.format(step, loss_value))
                else:
                    _, loss_value = sess.run((update_op, loss))
                step += 1

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            # we're through the dataset
            pass
        writer.close()
        saver.save(sess,save_path)
    print('Final loss: {}'.format(loss_value))

def serial_training(model_fn, dataset):

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    loss = model_fn(lambda: iterator.get_next())
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
    summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.0002)
    global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()


    update_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

    do_training(update_op, loss, summary_op)

tf.reset_default_graph()

serial_training(training_model,training_dataset(epochs=3,batch_size=batch_size))
```

Comment: How does your while loop stop?

Comment: Honestly I am not sure. I got this piece of the code from here - http://blog.s-schoener.com/2017-12-15-parallel-tensorflow-intro/
I assume that since the data is prepared using tf.data, it stops after it runs out of the steps

Comment: Oh now I see, thats why the try and except block is there. Ok regarding your problem how do you load your data? Do use follow the piece of code that you have provided, that means do you call ` dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(all_data_points)` somewhere in your code? Because there seems to be a bug with tensorflow that writes the data to your log file when you load the data like that. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1252

Comment: Yes, that is how I load the data. So, does that mean we should not use tensorboard when loading data that way? Or we don't load using tf.data. it does make sense because the files are much smaller when I run the same code for a considerably smaller dataset. Also, the events files are half a gb even when the write.summary hasn't run. Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: This https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_numpy_arrays might be worth trying. Instead of loading the numpy arrays into the dataset, you use placeholders instead and load the data dynamically into the graph.